# using WebSercurity.CreateAccount with other queries in a TrasactionScope, without DTC Enabled

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, entity-framework-5, transactionscope, msdtc, simplemembership

**Problem.** In a registration scenario, I'm trying to insert a user in my User table and then call `WebSercurity.CreateAccount` for that user (in a transaction). This causes the error that MS DTC is not available on the server.

**Description.** The reason I'm doing this is because I have a `Customer` Entity which inherits from `User`, so `WebSercurity.CreateUserAndAccount` cannot be used because it doesn't know about `Customer` and just inserts a `User` record.

I'm using Asp.net MVC 4 with EntityFramework 5, CodeFirst, and SQL Server 2008 R2.

any suggestions for not using DTC would be appreciated!

**EDIT.**
It is obvious why this error occurs, because websecurity uses its own connection to the database, and my repositories use another connection, although I've configured simplemembership to use the same `DbContext` class as my repositories, but the problem is it creates a new instance of the `DbContext` ...

I was hoping if there is a way to pass an existing context object, or connection to the `WebSecurity` to use with its methods.

here's the code:

```
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            //using (TransactionScope tx = new TransactionScope())
            //{
                UnitOfWork.UserRepository.Insert(new Customer
                {
                    FirstName = model.FirstName,
                    LastName = model.LastName,
                    Email = model.Email,
                    Tel = model.Tel,
                    Mobile = model.Mobile,
                    BirthDate = model.BirthDate,
                    InsertDate = DateTime.Now,
                    UserType = UserType.Customer,
                    MaritalStatus = model.MaritalStatus,
                    ZipCode = model.ZipCode,
                    StreetAddress = model.StreetAddress,
                    City = model.City,
                    State = model.State
                });
                UnitOfWork.Commit();

                string token = WebSecurity.CreateAccount(model.Email, model.Password, true);

                Roles.AddUserToRole(model.Email, "Customer");
                //WebSecurity.Login(model.Email, model.Password, true);

                await Task.Run(() => EmailHelper.SendConfrimationEmail(token, model.Email));

            //  tx.Complete();
            //}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found a **possible solution** but I'm not sure if it's the best solution. The idea came from this [blog post](http://blog.spontaneouspublicity.com/including-asp-net-simple-membership-tables-as-part-of-your-entity-framework-model) that says how we can include simplemembership tables in our POCO entities and create the tables ourselves (not using WebSecurity).

So as a result I think I can implement the `CreateAccount` method in my repositories by simply inserting a record in the `webpages_Membership` table, and `AddUserToRole` by inserting a record in `webpages_UsersInRoles` table.
For other queries like `GetUser` and ... we can use `WebSecurity` and `Roles` class like before.

It seems to work OK (otherwise I'm missing something), but has some extra work to do which I wish not to!

So if anyone can give me a better solution I would be glad.

Answer (score 1):

The DTC error occurs because you are trying to span a transaction over two different database connections.  You have several options.

SimpleMembership is designed for simple scenarios.  You are doing an advanced scenario, so you should probably use a different membership provider.

Comment: Thanks, Yes I know, isn't there a way to pass connection to the `WebSecurity` methods?

what membership providers do you suggest?

Answer (score 0):

As Mystere Man pointed out the error is occurring because the transaction is over two different databases. You have several options. Here are a few that come to mind.

You can customize the existing User entity used by the SimpleMembership provider to capture the custom information you want for each user. This is fairly straightforward and is [discussed in this blog post](http://kevin-junghans.blogspot.com/2013/01/seeding-customizing-aspnet-mvc.html). It looks like you are trying to do an email confirmation which the SimpleMembership provider also supports and is [discussed here](http://kevin-junghans.blogspot.com/2013/02/adding-email-confirmation-to.html).

You can also tie the information in your other database with the unique user ID (int) that SimpleMembership uses. Once you create the user and log them in you can get that id by calling [WebSecurity.CurrentUserId](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/webmatrix.webdata.websecurity.currentuserid%28v=vs.111%29.aspx).

You could bypass the whole SimpleMempership provider and create your own custom membership provider, which is [discussed here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/f1kyba5e%28v=vs.100%29.aspx).

Comment: Thank you for the answer.
about **option 1**: I'm exactly using this approach. my `User` entity has custom info I need, my problem is I have 2 types of User: Customer and Agent whitch inherits User!
about **option 2**: I'm doing this one too! My problem is something else (or I didn't get your point!). but the link had some useful information. thanks.
and about **option 3**: I don't want to reinvent the wheel.